# Loading Ajax Page

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-component

i want to make some loading process on my mini project in vue js , can anyone help me how to make loading process like step two ?

[step one example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GCId.png)

[step two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze3RT.png)

and when the loading is over this is the final output 
[final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgdgc.png)

thx anyone ..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm afraid this question will be considered as too broad for SO.

Comment: Basicly you'd need to show the step two once the ajax function get's fired and switch to step 3 on success.